# Is there any way to convert this if function to switch case type?

Tags: flutter, dart, if-statement, switch-statement

```
if (textLetter.toLowerCase().contains('1')) {
      textCodeElec += ' 19';
      textLetter = textLetter.substring(1); 
    }
    if (textLetter.toLowerCase().contains('2')) {
      textCodeElec += ' 00';
      textLetter = textLetter.substring(1);
    }
    if (textLetter.toLowerCase().contains('3')) {
      textCodeElec += ' 70';
      textLetter = textLetter.substring(1);
    }
    if (textLetter.toLowerCase().contains('4')) {
      textCodeElec += ' 08';
      textLetter = textLetter.substring(1);
    }
    if (textLetter.toLowerCase().contains('5')) {
      textCodeElec += ' 56';
      textLetter = textLetter.substring(1);
    }
    if (textLetter.toLowerCase().contains('6')) {
      textCodeElec += ' 68';
      textLetter = textLetter.substring(1);
    }
    if (textLetter.toLowerCase().contains('7')) {
      textCodeElec += ' 20';
      textLetter = textLetter.substring(1);
    }
    if (textLetter.toLowerCase().contains('8')) {
      textCodeElec += ' 16';
      textLetter = textLetter.substring(1);
    }
    if (textLetter.toLowerCase().contains('9')) {
      textCodeElec += ' 27';
      textLetter = textLetter.substring(1);
    }
```

I still don't know how to solve this problem
When entering 1 to 9, textCodeElec will display conditionally, but entering 9 to 1 backwards will only display a number.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTaU7.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PR0K3.png)

Comment: i don't know what problem you are trying to solve. you could add an input and an expected output. but looking at your code, probably you should iterate the textLetter letter by letter and use switch case inside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try and i hope it fixes your problem.

```
String someFunc(val) {
  String textLetter = val;
  final textToList = textLetter.split('');
  // textToList.sort();//if you need to sorted number uncomment this line
  final result = textToList.map((e) => codecVal(e)).toList();
  return result.join("");
}

String codecVal(val) {
  switch (val) {
    case '1':
      return ' 19';
    case '2':
      return ' 00';
    case '3':
      return ' 70';
    case '4':
      return ' 08';
    case '5':
      return ' 56';
    case '6':
      return ' 68';
    case '7':
      return ' 20';
    case '8':
      return ' 16';
    case '9':
      return ' 27';
    default:
      return "";
  }
}
```

input=987654321

output= 27 16 20 68 56 08 70 00 19

---

input=123456789

output=19 00 70 08 56 68 20 16 27